# Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread when using Mono.retryWhen

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactor

I am using the Reactor library within the Spring WebFlux to call external API via HTTP and retry the request in case of any errors occurred. I need to access a `request`-scoped bean inside the method which can be retried. Before the first unsuccessful request, I have the bean defined in the current context but after retrying failed attempt the context is lost. I can't access the `request`-scoped bean from inside the same method. **The question is how do I pass the web context for the request-scoped bean to the next retry?**

My code where the bean is defined:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
@Validated
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class RequesterInfo {

    @Email
    private String email;
    private String id;
    private String authType;
}
```

The code where retry is happening:

```
            Mono
                .fromSupplier(() -> myMethod(argument))
                .doOnSuccess(result -> log.info("...", result))
                .doOnError(error -> log.error("...", error))
                .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(retryAttempts, retryMinBackoff)
                    .doBeforeRetry(retrySignal -> log.error("...", retrySignal.totalRetries()))
                    .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) -> retrySignal.failure()));
```

`argument` to `myMethod` is a lambda where `requesterInfo` is accessed

The error message as such:

```
2022-04-18 10:46:34.082 [parallel-1] ERROR com.praytic.MyClass[] - .... 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.requesterInfo': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem right now.

Comment: I had to use my custom scheduler which retains `RequesterInfo` bean until the end.